# unfamiliar C shorthand { }

Tags: c, syntax

I inherited some code and it has a format like this when it is called.  To be clear some function is defined somewhere like this:

```
void some_function(int a, int b, int c){
     printf("hi there\n");
}
```

then it is called like this in the main code:

```
some_function(2, 3, 4);
{
       x = 1200;
       another_function(&x);
}
```

So is the above just short hand for:

```
if(some_function(2,3,4) == 1)
{
    //then execute code found here?
}
```

I've never seen that one before, and I feel that since some_function is void and  never returns a value that it will never run the code in the brackets?

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in your debugger to see what happens?

Comment: some_function is void so you cannot use the return value.  Are you sure you copied the code correctly?  I expect a semicolon on the first line of the second code block.

Comment: Are you sure it’s not `some_function(…); { … }`? In other words, a call to a function, followed by a block of code.

Comment: Yes sorry my slip I was writing an example not copying directly, that's probably against the rules here :)  ; added in the correct place now.

Comment: `{{{{}}}}` is a valid statement in C.

Comment: Guys, please flag this question to help it being closed.

Comment: @Iman: Why do you want it to be closed?

Comment: @KeithThompson the question seems very unclear, if you understood the intention of the question owner, I wish to ask you to edit the question.

Comment: @Iman: The question seems clear enough to me. The function call followed by a compound statement looks confusingly similar to an `if` statement. The explanation is that the compound statement is not related to the function call, other than the fact that it happens to follow it.

Comment: @KeithThompson it is so much better now(edited couple of ten minutes ago)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *compound statement* is a `{`, followed by zero or more declarations and statements, followed by a `}`. A compound statement is treated as a single statement.

Typically a compound statement is used as the statement controlled by an `if`, `while`, `for`, etc.:

```
if (condition)
{
    blah;
    blah;
}
```

but it can be used anywhere you can use a single statement. (Compound statements are sometimes called *blocks*; strictly speaking a compound statement is one kind of block.)

It can be useful as a way to define a local variable:

```
 blah;
 {
     int n = 42;
     /* ... */
 }
 /* n is not visible here */
```

In your example:

```
some_function(2, 3, 4);
{
       x = 1200;
       another_function(&x);
}
```

the extra `{` and `}` are legal, but useless; they could be omitted with no change to the meaning of the program. (The author might have intended to mark those statements as a *logical* grouping.)

The compound statement is not logically related to the function call; it just happens to follow it.

Using a compound statement here would make more sense if the code were something like:

```
some_function(2, 3, 4);
{
       int x = 1200;
       another_function(&x);
}
```

since it would provide a local scope for the variable `x`.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid syntax but serves no good purpose in this case.  Removing the extra braces would not change the meaning of the code.

Putting additional braces is sometimes useful, however, if you want to restrict the scope of a local variable.  For example, if I want to exchange the values of `a` and `b`, I might write

```
int a;
int b;

// Lots of code that assigns values to `a` and `b`.

{
  int temp;
  temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
}
```

so not to litter the namespace with the `temp` variable.  This is even more useful in C++ where destructors for variables with automatic storage duration will be run automatically at scope exit.